# How can I run a Minecraft Server on multiple CPU cores? Mac

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

How can I set my bukkit server on my mac to use more than 1 core? I set my server to use 12 gigs of RAM for now, considering that I will be adding more servers soon.

My iMac has these configurations:

- 3.5GHz Quad-core Intel Core i7, Turbo Boost up to 3.9GHz
- 32GB 1600MHz DDR3 SDRAM - 4X8GB
- 1TB of PCIe-Based Flash Storage
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 780M 4GB GDDR5

It uses mavericks.

Also, is it possible to use the graphics card for the server (considering that the RAM on it is MUCH faster than the standard 1600MHz RAM) when the card is not in use?

Thanks so much guys!

Comment: I use Java JDK if that helps.

Comment: Although you are using a mac, the question linked above will still apply to you. You just need to edit your startup script.

Comment: It seems like there are two questions built into this, but other than that, this question seems pretty good.

Comment: How would I edit the script?

Comment: Any idea guys on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of [How can I run a Minecraft Server on multiple CPU cores?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/104527/how-can-i-run-a-minecraft-server-on-multiple-cpu-cores), but here's some JVM flags you need:

```
-server -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing -XX:ParallelGCThreads=7 -XX:+AggressiveOpts
```

(from https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/105638/51845)