# Can I get a Linux Minecraft server to use multithreading?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition-server, linux

I am using a raspberry pi 4B to run a Minecraft server. It has a quad-core CPU at 1.5GHZ. I am also using spigot 1.16.5. Is it possible to make Minecraft use all CPU cores instead of just one? I am also able to use Linux commands, as I am running the raspberry pi OS. This would be good to have, because I could build a supercomputer with a raspberry pi to get 8 or even 12 cores.

Comment: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/105638 This is already answered here. Hope it helps.

Comment: Procedurally casting close vote per lmmuc's comment.

Answer (score 3):

To put it simply, no, you cannot do so without rewriting most of the game.

This means if you want better server performance, get the best single-thread CPU you can buy. The good news is that these days, ARM platforms have nearly caught up. Your raspberry-pi is at about 1/8<sup>th</sup> of the speed of the fastest processors available (writing June 2021), so you could do a lot better by running instead on something like a recent laptop/low-power processor. When it comes to standalone products, something like a PN51 or mac mini (similar power requirements, available as a standalone NUC). A cheap PC<sup>2</sup> is another option. Or you could rent a 1-core VPS. Of course, once you start wanting to run *many* servers, then server CPU machines will work best.

In fact, the minecraft devs did just that for this, and other reasons, and made Bedrock Edition, which is natively written. This means: Instead of using intermediate bytecode, directly compiled to x86(-64) or ARM assembly.

*Clustering*<sup>1</sup>, on the other hand is not supported (by either game) and I don't think it's very likely that it ever will be. While theoretically possible, this too means essentially writing your own server code from the ground up.

1: By this I mean a server that runs on multiple machines, communicating to provide redundancy and share workload in-between them, using load-balancing, fencing, and other advanced techniques.

2: This won't be as power-efficient for 24/7 operation; as PCs nowadays have many cores but pretty poor single-core power efficiency. While e.g. a 16-core CPU won't use 100% power when only one core is loaded, the real figure is going to be closer to 30% than the ~7% you'd expect. You *could* however optimize this: set lower maximum turbo speeds for your CPU. For example, looking at [this article](https://www.anandtech.com/show/16214/amd-zen-3-ryzen-deep-dive-review-5950x-5900x-5800x-and-5700x-tested/8), it seems that you could get only 1/3<sup>rd</sup> the power draw by lowering the turbo frequency from 5 GHz to arond 3.5 GHz. If you're willing to tweak your computer a bit it's quite easily possible to get massive efficiency benefits by underclocking it by about 20-30%.